# Mat-datepicker value doesn't pass to function

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to pass a value from my mat-datepicker (angular material) to a function so that I can append it to my dateArray. For example, if the user selects 31st of January on the datepicker, this value should be passed to my addDate function, which then pushes the value to the array. I have tried using date.value, but angular doesn't accept it. I have also tried using date.stringify(), but with no luck. Is there another way to pass it to the function? Would appreciate any help very much!

Many thanks

```
//html component
<mat-form-field>
        <input matInput name='date' #Date id='Date' #Date [matDatepicker]="Date"
               ngModel='Date' placeholder='When  do you have this subject?' required>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="Date"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker touchUi="true" #Date></mat-datepicker>
        <mat-datepicker #Date></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>

<button mat-button type='button' (click)='addDate(Date.value)'>Add date</button>

// component.ts

addDate(Date) {
this.dateArray.push(Date)
}
```

Comment: Try to change the variable name, `Date` is the datatype

Comment: Thanks for the reply! No success unfortunately.

Comment: Are there any errrors in the console?

Comment: Yep, http://imgur.com/a/xmBXk